# How do I make a setf-able a macro that will either return a form that returns a parameter or a form that returns a default number

Tags: common-lisp

I have this macro

```
(defmacro get-priority (todo)
  `(or (and (listp (car ,todo))
           (cdr (assoc 'priority ,todo)))
      0))
```

Which is called like so

```
CL-USER> (get-priority '(Make stack overflow question))
0
CL-USER> (get-priority '((priority . 10)(Make stack overflow question)))
10
```

I need to be able to set the result of  `get-priority`. In the case that calling the macro result returns a default 0, I want to just setf a temporary place. Perhaps some use of gensym will solve my problem.

PS. This is my first CL macro.

Comment: You could just have a `GET-PRIORITY` function which can return a default value and define a `(SETF GET-PRIORITY)` (note that this is a legal function name in Common Lisp) function to do whatever you want it to.

Comment: Alternatively see [`DEFINE-SETF-EXPANDER`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_defi_3.htm)

Comment: You can't generally SETF results. SETF is used to set PLACES. A place is not a physical thing, but more like a concept to generalize ways to set things. Generally a place might look like an accessor, but it is really description which SETF takes to compute a setter. In `(setf (foo bar) :baz)` setf does not set the result of `(foo bar)`, but it looks at the form `(foo bar)` itself at macro expansion time (!) to compute the setter code. This new code is then executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two existing methods that work well in most cases: mutating containers (like hash-tables) or manipulating immutable data (like association lists).
What you are trying to do is mutating association lists, which is made a little bit harder to implement correctly and goes counter to the intended usage. It is however still possible to write a macro, as demonstrated below.

### Hash tables

If you are going to modify properties, you can simply use hash tables:

```
(gethash 'priority environment 0)
=> Either the current priority, or zero if no priority is set

(setf (gethash 'priority environment) 10)
=> Replaces priority
```

Or even:

```
(incf (gethash 'priority environment 0))
=> Increment current priority (which defaults to zero)
```

See [`MAKE-HASH-TABLE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_has.htm) and [`GETHASH`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_gethas.htm).

### Association lists

Association lists can be considered superior to hash-tables when you want to quickly inherit values from other environments.
The way [`ASSOC`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm) works is by finding the *first* match in a list, which means you can have multiple occurrences of `priority`, where the first one shadows the others.

```
(defun increase-priority (environment value)
  (acons 'priority 
         (+ (or (cdr (assoc 'priority env)) 0)
            value)
         environment))
```

See [`ACONS`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_acons.htm).

Here above, the existing environment is not modified. A new one is built, on top of the previous one. They both share the same sublist. Supposing you have a function named `process` which accepts a value and an environment, and that `env` is already bound to an environment, you could call:

```
 (process value (increase-priority env 1))
```

The intermediate environment would only be visible inside the function call, while `env` is left untouched.
You could manage to do the same with hash tables, provided you copy existing hash tables or take care of undoing temporary changes.

### Modifying places

You generally do not want to modify association lists: unlike hash tables, you do not have a single container that you can mutate easily. The empty association list is the symbol `nil`: you cannot mutate that empty list to add a new element. 
A possible way to bypass the issue is to keep a structure which holds the head of the association list (this is what the next section does).
Another approach is to use macros, which can acceptunevaluated expressions that represents *binding* and more generally a *place*: if a variable `env` holds a nil association list, you want to set `env` to the new list. Also, as demonstrated in your example, you risk mutating constant data: you quoted your list, which in Common Lisp means the data should be treated as a constant; but then you tried to modify it, which has undefined behavior.

Like [`PUSH`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm), your macro is allowed to set the place holding the list being modified. You could define your own macro with [`DEFINE-SETF-EXPANDER`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_3.htm), as said in comments:

```
(define-setf-expander get-priority (list)
  (let ((current (gensym))
        (new-priority (gensym)))
    (values (list current)
            (list `(assoc 'priority ,list))
            (list new-priority)
            `(prog1 ,new-priority
               (if ,current
                   (setf (cdr ,current) ,new-priority)
                   (setf ,list
                         (list* (cons 'priority ,new-priority)
                                ,list))))
            `(if ,current (cdr ,current) 0))))
```

Basically, we fetch the existing cons cell where `'priority` is in `car` position, and replaces its `cdr`. But if we do not find such a cons cell, we push instead a fresh cons cell in front of the existing list. Either way, the code must return the new priority (this is part of the contract of [`SETF`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/a_setf.htm)). Here is an example:

```
(let ((list ()))
  (print list)
  (print (setf (get-priority list) 10))
  (print list)
  (print (setf (get-priority list) 20))
  (print list)
  (values))
```

The above prints:

```
NIL 
10 
((PRIORITY . 10)) 
20 
((PRIORITY . 20))
```

And here is the macroexpansion for `(setf (get-priority list) 20)` (under SBCL):

```
(LET* ((#:G757 (ASSOC 'PRIORITY LIST)) (#:G758 20))
  (PROG1 #:G758
    (IF #:G757
        (SETF (CDR #:G757) #:G758)
        (SETF LIST (LIST* (CONS 'PRIORITY #:G758) LIST)))))
```

The last value return by the setf-expander is used when `get-priority` is set by modifying its existing value. For example, the following expression:

```
(let ((list (list)))
  (incf (get-priority list)))
```

is macroexpanded as:

```
(LET ((LIST (LIST)))
  (LET* ((#:G771 (ASSOC 'PRIORITY LIST))
         (#:G772
          (+ 1
             (IF #:G771
                 (CDR #:G771)
                 0))))
    (LET ((#:G773 #:G772))
      (IF #:G771
          (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACD #:G771 #:G772)
          (SETQ LIST (LIST* (CONS 'PRIORITY #:G772) LIST)))
      #:G773)))
```

You can see that variable `#:G772` is the new value, computed from the current one, which is either extracted from the cons cell or defaults to zero.
Note that the expansion works also when using it with more complex places:

```
(let ((hash (make-hash-table)))
  (setf (gethash 'cons hash) (cons (list (cons 'priority 0)) :dummy))
  (setf (get-priority (car (gethash 'cons hash))) 100)
  (maphash (lambda (k v) (print v)) hash))

=> (((PRIORITY . 100)) . :DUMMY)
```

Macroexpansion:

```
(LET* ((#:G759 (ASSOC 'PRIORITY (CAR (GETHASH 'CONS HASH)))) (#:G760 100))
  (LET ((#:G761 #:G760))
    (IF #:G759
        (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACD #:G759 #:G760)
        (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA (GETHASH 'CONS HASH) (LIST* (CONS 'PRIORITY #:G760) (CAR (GETHASH 'CONS HASH)))))
    #:G761))
```

It is not recommended you use the above setf expansion. Anyway, if you write macros, take care about unwanted *mutliple evaluations*: your code evaluates `todo` twice. Instead, use [`GENSYM`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_gensym.htm) to define local variables which hold the values of forms you only want evaluated once (or, see the interesting [`ONCE-ONLY`](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Macro-Writing) macro).

### Dedicated container

Instead of macros, you can also wrap your list (either nil or a cons-cell) into a container:

```
(defstruct (association-list
            (:constructor alist (&optional head))
            (:conc-name alist-))
  head)
```

Then, you can mutate the `head` slot as desired.

```
(defun aget (alist property &optional default)
  (etypecase alist
    (null default)
    (cons (let ((result (assoc property alist)))
            (if result
                (values (cdr result) result)
                default)))
    (association-list
     (aget (alist-head alist) property default))))

(defmacro apush (key value alist)
  `(push (cons ,key ,value) (alist-head ,alist)))

(defun (setf aget) (value alist property)
  (let ((existing (assoc property (alist-head alist))))
    (prog1 value
      (if existing
          (setf (cdr existing) value)
          (apush property value alist)))))
```

For example:

```
(let ((alist (alist)))
  (print (aget alist 'priority 0))
  (print (setf (aget alist 'priority) 10))
  (print alist)
  (print (setf (aget alist 'priority) 20))
  (print alist)
  (values))
```

... prints:

```
0 
10 
#S(ASSOCIATION-LIST :HEAD ((PRIORITY . 10))) 
20 
#S(ASSOCIATION-LIST :HEAD ((PRIORITY . 20)))
```

However, you probably also need to implement additional helper functions, and this is slightly not idiomatic when it comes to association lists. Prefer using them in an immutable way.